# Update deprecated php platform on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I log in Elastic Beanstalk, I see that my platform is deprecated:

[image: Deprecated platform]

I guess it is because of the 7.2 PHP version that is now unsupported.

But when I click on change I don't see any higher version. In addition I can't find where in ElasticBeanstalk I can change the PHP version of my app.
[image: available platforms]

Comment: How did it go?  Is it still unclear how to upgrade your EB?

Comment: Hi @Marcin, sorry I did not have time to try out your answer yet, I'll make sure to keep you informed and update the question here when it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The support for `64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.17 running PHP 7.2` finished on [May 2, 2021](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platform-history-php.html). The only [current](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.PHP) versions of EB for PHP are based on **Amazon Linux 2** (AL2).

Since AL1 is largely different then AL1 (what you have now), the only way to upgrade is to perform **migration** from AL1 to AL2 as explained in:

- [Migrating your Elastic Beanstalk Linux application to Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html)

Comment: Hi @Marcin, I managed to upgrade my environment thanks!  But I encounter a new issue now - for which I created another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67582584/elastic-beanstalk-replace-htaccess-for-nginx-after-upgrade